# Multiple Http configuration using both java and xml configuration not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an app that loads a default spring security configuration from a java class with the option of importing addition configuration from a external file as such:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
@ImportResource("file:///${my.home.dir}\\conf\\security.xml")
public class WebSecurityConfiguration implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6654777887140629668L;

@Configuration
@Order
public static class AnotherWebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements Serializable { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 4628321113541373781L;  
public AnotherWebSecurityConfiguration() {
super();
}  
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
web.ignoring().antMatchers(ignoredUrls); // we want to disable Spring Security for static resources.
}
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").and().httpBasic().and().csrf().disable();
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
}
```

The external file contains the following:

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" pattern="/manage/app/**" authentication-manager-ref="anotherAuthenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/manage/app/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

 <authentication-manager id="anotherAuthenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
                    <user name="admin" password="admin2" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

so basically i am saying is that i need to have 2 authentication access points:

> /** and /manage/app/**

when i execute the app I get the following error:

> Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager but
>   3 where found...

So i added the following method to the main class WebSecurityConfiguration

```
protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
}
```

in this case the xml security configuration is working properly, but the java configuration is beeing ignored.

Can you please tell what did i do wrong in the configuration?

Note that i am using spring security 3.2

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

XML configuration overrides java config - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7341 . I dont see a reason why you want to mix those, investing some time in rewriting this now will save your time in a future :) You can probably use http.antMatchers(...) with and() to merge both configs.